# NIFI EXECUTESCRIPT Processor failing - No MODULE FOUND

Tags: apache-nifi, jython, execute-script, flowfile

I am trying to import modules into executescript processor in nifi.
As suggested , I. am giving full path into the modules directory.

example: 
Module Directory: */var/lib/nifi/Levenshtein* --> which contains necessary files for the script.

Furthermore, In the script also I have set the system path pointing to use that module directory
My code Looks something like this

```py
import re
import datetime
import sys
sys.path.append('/var/lib/nifi/Levenshtein')

import Levenshtein
```

When I am running the processor with above code it fails.

> ERROR: No Module named Levenshtein in  at line number 3.

Comment: @mattyb if you can help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this particular library is a "native module" (compiled C code), Jython (the Python execution engine used by `ExecuteScript`) will not be able to load it. `ExecuteScript` in NiFi using Python can only use pure Python code.

The work-around is to use `ExecuteProcess` or `ExecuteStreamCommand` and invoke `python <my_script.py>` on the command-line, which can handle various Python versions, native modules, etc. This execution will occur outside the JVM and use real Python, not Jython.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up what Andy said, this [Levensthein module](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/) is written in C and cannot be executed by a Java virtual machine, assuming you are running a Jython implementation.

Comment: Thank @Bugbeeb for your explanation.